# Unable to automate web-scraping process with rvest and follow_link

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My supervisor and I are working on a research paper regarding the impact of the temporary decriminalization of indoor sex work in Rhode Island. As part of our data collection, we're trying to scrape theeroticreview.com for data on sex worker characteristics, average prices, and some other data. There are way too many profiles to enter by hand, so I am trying to write an R script to automate the process.

Currently, my code looks like this:  [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5tqU.png). As you see, I have to enter each name for each profile separately or I get a "no links have text with" error. There are 2000 observations. Xpaths aren't playing nice format-wise.

```
##Set Main Page 
TER <- html_session("https://www.theeroticreview.com/reviews/newreviewsList.asp?searchreview=1&gCity=region1%2Dus%2Drhode%2Disland&gCityName=Rhode+Island+%28State%29&SortBy=3&gDistance=0")
##Locate and follow link to profile
reviews <- TER %>% follow_link('Ashley')
## extract required information
reviews %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
##back to main page 
rhea <- reviews %>% back()
revieww <- TER %>% follow_link("Lily")
revieww %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
rhea <- revieww %>% back()
reviewa <- TER %>% follow_link("Coco")
reviewa %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
rhea <- reviewa %>% back()
##Move to Next Page 
TER %>% jump_to('https://www.theeroticreview.com/reviews/newreviewsList.asp?Valid=1&mp=0&SortBy=3&searchreview=1&gCity=region1-us-rhode-island&gDistance=0&gCityName=Rhode%20Island%20(State)&page=2')
TER2 <- html_session('https://www.theeroticreview.com/reviews/newreviewsList.asp?Valid=1&mp=0&SortBy=3&searchreview=1&gCity=region1-us-rhode-island&gDistance=0&gCityName=Rhode%20Island%20(State)&page=2')
reviewd <- TER2 %>% follow_link('Danielle')
reviewd %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
```

On the HTML of the site, each link is td-name. Is there any way to write an algorithm/code a function so that this process is automated?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you aren't violating the site's terms of service in scraping this data, especially if you're planning on publishing research based on this data.

I don't think you need a headless browser to get what you need, and if you can avoid using one you should. Here's a bit of code that will get you the links associated with each profile.

```
profile_url_lst <- list()
for(page_num in 1:73){
  
  main_url <- paste0("https://www.theeroticreview.com/reviews/newreviewsList.asp?searchreview=1&gCity=region1%2Dus%2Drhode%2Disland&gCityName=Rhode+Island+%28State%29&SortBy=3&gDistance=0&page=", page_num)
  
  html_content <- read_html(main_url)
  
  profile_urls <- html_content %>% html_nodes("body") %>% html_children() %>% html_children() %>% .[2] %>% html_children() %>% 
    html_children() %>% .[3] %>% html_children() %>% .[4] %>% html_children() %>% html_children() %>% html_children() %>% 
    html_attr("href")
  
  profile_url_lst[[page_num]] <- profile_urls

}
```

This worked for a few pages. I haven't run the whole loop. You may also want to include `Sys.sleep(2)` at the end of the loop so as not to overwhelm their servers. I'd look more deeply into scraping this site but my computer is next to a window and I don't want to give my neighbors the wrong impression.

Comment: Many thanks! That grabs the URLs. If I were to combine the listed profile URLs with the follow_link tool to then scrape the data from the profiles, what would that look like?

Comment: wouldn't `html_content %>% html_nodes('.ter-table a') %>% html_attr('href')` be a lot easier and more robust?

Comment: Yup, that appears to work just fine. @thenotsopolitecanadian, I'd avoid using the follow_link tool. Instead, create a loop iterating through the profile urls based on the links you've collected. At each iteration, collect whatever content you need directly from each profile page.

Comment: That makes sense, but what does the code for that look like? My base URL is the page of search results, and I need it to go into the profile, extract from it, and then continue to the next result/profile and do the same thing.